# Running shell command from Python script

Tags: python

I'm trying to run a shell command from within a python script which needs to do several things
1. The shell command is 'hspice tran.deck >! tran.lis'
2. The script should wait for the shell command to complete before proceeding
3. I need to check the return code from the command and
4. Capture STDOUT if it completed successfully else capture STDERR

I went through the subprocess module and tried out a couple of things but couldn't find a way to do all of the above.
- with subprocess.call() I could check the return code but not capture the output.
- with subprocess.check_output() I could capture the output but not the code.
- with subprocess.Popen() and Popen.communicate(), I could capture STDOUT and STDERR but not the return code.
I'm not sure how to use Popen.wait() or the returncode attribute. I also couldn't get Popen to accept '>!' or '|' as arguments.

Can someone please point me in the right direction? I'm using Python 2.7.1

EDIT: Got things working with the following code

```
process = subprocess.Popen('ls | tee out.txt', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = process.communicate()
if(process.returncode==0):
  print out
else:
  print err
```

Also, should I use a *process.wait()* after the *process = line* or does it wait by default?

Comment: communicate() waits for the process to exit http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just use [`.returncode`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.returncode) after `.communicate()`. Also, tell Popen that [what you're trying to run is a shell command](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor), rather than a raw command line:

```
p = subprocess.Popen('ls | tee out.txt', shell=True, ...)
p.communicate()
print p.returncode
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I've updated my question with the code that I'm using right now. Would you know how to specify PIPE and redirection in the shell command?

Comment: @Ronin: You don't seem to like the documentation very much, it's in the exact same paragraph I linked to. For your maximum convenience, I added example code for that as well.

Comment: Niklas, I was referring the documentation before I'd posted this question. My mistake was that I'd specified the arguments to Popen as an anonymous array. I'm very new to python; I'll accept the admonishment. Thanks for the code.

Comment: @Ronin: In that case, no worries. Glad to help, have fun coding and come back to this site if you need help :)

Answer (score 3):

From [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.returncode):

> `Popen.`**`returncode`**
>
> The child return code, set by `poll()` and `wait()` (and indirectly by `communicate()`). A None value indicates that the process hasn’t terminated yet.
>
> A negative value `-N` indicates that the child was terminated by signal `N` (Unix only).

Answer (score -1):

Here is example how to interact with shell:

```
>>> process = subprocess.Popen(['/bin/bash'], shell=False, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> process.stdin.write('echo it works!\n')
>>> process.stdout.readline()
'it works!\n'
>>> process.stdin.write('date\n')
>>> process.stdout.readline()
'wto, 13 mar 2012, 17:25:35 CET\n'
>>>
```